# Как осуществить выборку предыдущих значений на mysql + php?

Tags: php, mysql

Читается, конечно, выборка по id - N с последующим LIMIT 0, N, но это 2 запроса. Напрямую через MySQL можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то не понятно, что это у вас за 2 запроса. Вы имеете ввиду нечто такое?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `tbl` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT N
```